# How to write alias for bash command that finds and checkouts a branch

Tags: linux, bash, git, terminal, alias

I'd like to create an alias or a function to find a branch by part of its name and checkout it. It can be done with `git branch | grep <search-string> | xargs git checkout` but it is cumbersome to write it every time. I tried to write a function (below) but it looks like even the `git branch` part does not work in it.

Any advises on how it could be done?

```
function grep_checkout {
        local checkout_command="git branch | grep $1 | xargs git checkout"

        echo $($checkout_command)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `fzf` for that, I have the following alias:

```
alias gco='git checkout $(git branch | grep -v $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | fzf)'
```

It is described on the project page how to set it up: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Then, I type `gco`, press return, then I find my branch and return again to run the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

you write same way as you write any other aliases:

```
alias fcb = 'git branch | grep <search-string> | xargs git checkout '
```

whenever you need to run this command use fcb; you can write this in your main or profile bash config so you don't have to set it on every run of the console.

PS. I don't have nix machine available so did not check if the command actually works - just re-used what you provided, hoping it does what you want.

Comment: I'd rather use `$1` than `<search-string>`

Comment: I've tried `alias fcb='git branch | grep $1 | xargs git checkout '` but apparently `git checkout` command gets $1 as parameter and not the result of `git branch | grep $1`